# Multi Level Nested JSON Parsing with Apex Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

Can I parse Multi-Level nested `JSON` structure in `APEX Salesforce`, like we do in Java with `GSON` and `Jackson` libraries?

```
{
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":{

          "key3":"value3",
          "key4":{
                 "key5":"value5"
           }

    }
}
```

I have already explored this.

[Parsing JSON in Apex Salesforce](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_json_jsonparser.htm)

But I want a generic solution which will parse any JSON to the required Apex Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using the serialize/deserialize methods of the JSON class in Apex:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm

You'll need to construct an Apex class based on your input JSON, but there's even a handy tool to do it:

http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

Unfortunately however, you're limited by the depth of the Apex classes.  I think after key4 in your example, you're back to parsing it manually.

One thing to consider is building a partial model in Apex, then hydrating any deeper nested objects you need using the parser.